# RestKit Mapped Requests

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, restkit

I created some sort of wrapper class for my self for API requests as follows:

```
+ (void)sendGETRequestWithURLString:(NSString *)request mapping:(NSString *)mapping withFailBlock:(RKRequestDidFailLoadWithErrorBlock)failBlock completion:(kServiceCompleteBlock)completion {

    RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

    [manager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:request usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {        
        loader.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response) {
            [self fireErrorBlock:failBlock onErrorInResponse:response];
            if (completion)
                completion(response);
        };
    }];
}
```

I am trying to map the response. When I used RestKit 0.9, I mapped it in the AppDelegate as follows:

```
RKObjectMapping* categoryMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Category class]];
[categoryMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"categoryID"];
[categoryMapping mapKeyPath:@"name_ar" toAttribute:@"arabicName"];
[categoryMapping mapKeyPath:@"name_en" toAttribute:@"englishName"];
[categoryMapping mapKeyPath:@"img" toAttribute:@"imageUri"];
[categoryMapping mapKeyPath:@"img_en" toAttribute:@"imageEnUri"];
```

How would I connect the above mapping to my request in the former code above in 10.0?

Comment: What is your question? This mapping seem compatible for both versions

Comment: My request are not being mapped. I can't figure out how to map requests in version 0.10 with the new introduction of block sytnax.

Comment: Block syntax is optional. Don't use it if you don't want to.

Comment: I want to. No one seems to know how to get this done - might just move to `AFNetworking`.